# Git - checkout only part of (big) repository into working directory

Tags: git, git-checkout, working-directory

I've a pretty big Git repository. It's cloned from SVN via git-svn so there are many `branches/`, `tags/` and `trunk/` directories and thus a lot of duplicated files. I guess Git handles these files efficiently internally (magic under `.git/` directory). However working directory is full of (SVN) garbage.

Is it possible to checkout only part of reposiotry into working directory? How can I do it?

Thank you.

EDIT: The answer is "sparse checkout" feature of Git 1.7.0.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/is-there-any-way-to-clone-a-git-repositorys-sub-directory-only

Comment: Not true. I want clone _whole_ repository. I want to checkout only a part of it into working directory.

Comment: So you don't have a clone, you have a git repo tracking a local copy of an SVN repo. No? See the answer from @Andrew

Comment: I take it back. The answer is here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/is-there-any-way-to-clone-a-git-repositorys-sub-directory-only/2861204#2861204).

Answer (score 0):

If you've got many `branches` and  `tags` directories it sounds like you've done something wrong. When you import into Git you should have one repository with Git style branches and tags.

Github have a page [about importing into Git from Subversion](http://help.github.com/import-from-subversion/). They recommend using [svn2git](https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git). I've used sv2git with success.

Comment: The problem is that we have many "sub-repositories" in our SVN repository (which contains `branches/`, ...). These directories are nothing special in fact.

Comment: By the way you don't need svn2git anymore because git-svn now handles SVN tags and branches too.